# Calling an OnClickListener in an ArrayAdapter class

Tags: java, android

The Method status counts the clicks on one child of a ListView and safes the inside an ArrayList.  It is defined in the MainActivity.java.

```
public void status(int f) {
        int current = status.get(f);
        current++;
        status.set(f, current);
    }
```

Now, from the class of my custom ArrayAdapter in the getView methode, I want to call the class on one part of my ArrayAdapter, a Textview definded in a ViewHolder class.

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

holder.TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                int pos = holder.ListView.indexOfChild(view);
                main.status(pos);

            }
        });
```

Performing this code, I get a NullPointerException:

```
Process: com.example.philipp.einkaufsliste110, PID: 18364

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int 
android.widget.ListView.indexOfChild(android.view.View)' on a null object 
reference

at 

 com.example.philipp.einkaufsliste110.Adapter.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapt    er.java:64)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**Edit**

changed the  code in the ArrayAdapter class to:
(parent is the ViewGroup definded in getView Methode: `viewGroup parent`)

```
 holder.TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view2) {
                view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);


                int pos = parent.indexOfChild(view2);
                main.status(pos);

            }
        });
```

Now getting the Error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
                                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
```

How is that possible?

Comment: what exectly layout and view2 is?

Comment: @MohdSaquib edited it in. Take a look at the code.

Comment: Your **holder.ListView** is null

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran but how can it?

Comment: @Sarius, post your relevant code

Comment: okay, i changed the **holder.Listview** to parentGroup. lets see if that workd.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran take a look

Comment: May I know what do you want to achieve.?

Comment: I want to count the clicks on all TextViews and safe them in a List. If the number % 2  != 0, i wanna strike through the TetView when the App is entered. @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Comment: So you want the current clicked item position..?

Comment: Yes @muthukrishnanrajendran

Comment: Then, what is the problem of using the position from **getView** params

Comment: I'm not. I'm using the position from the OnClickListener. @muthukrishnanrajendran